# How to turn on the light in the dark room on candy box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

Ive read that it is "in the middle" of the room but I cannot for the life of me find the light switch.  Can someone be more descriptive on how to turn this light on?

Is it near the fire? Above or below? perhaps a screenshot??

Thanks!

Comment: The fire *is* the light switch.

Comment: I see no where to click on it tho?

Comment: That other thread does answer the question but not specifically enough

Comment: I think it can't be more specific than "center of the room" when the room is only a black rectangle.

Comment: Anyway, if you see the fire camp then you already lighted up the room. There is nothing more to do there.

Comment: No, really - the only way to be more specific here would be with a screenshot, but that screenshot would still just be all black and nothing of value.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a light switch.  The way the room becomes non dark is by lighting the fire.

This is likely an easter egg for the game [a-dark-room](/questions/tagged/a-dark-room), which you can play [here](http://adarkroom.doublespeakgames.com/).